# Vertical placement of \sidefootnote in memoir

Tags: vertical-alignment, memoir

I'm using the memoir class with a wide margin for marginfigures and side footnotes. According to memman, when `\sidefootadjust` is set to 0 side footnotes are placed at the bottom of the margin. In my MWE below they are placed near the bottom but not all the way down. I would like them placed as far down so I can use the space above them for margin figures.

**Question 1** If I change `\sidefootadjust` to something like 3cm I get the footnotes to go all the way down but before I make this change in the entire document I want to know why I don't get the behavior described in the manual at the default setting of 0.

**Question 2** If I comment out `\setlength{\sidefootwidth}{\marginparwidth}` the width of the footnote text becomes smaller than `\marginparwidth`. According to memman the default for `\sidefootwidth` *is* `\marginparwidth` but apparently I have to set it explicitly.

The issues may have to do with how I define the size of text, although I cannot see why.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\synctex=1
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

% page dimensions
\settypeblocksize{54.3163pc}{*}{0.5}
\setbinding{1pc}
\setlrmargins{4.312pc}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{6.1pc}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{0pt}{2.5\onelineskip}
\setmarginnotes{2pc}{12pc}{2\onelineskip}
\checkandfixthelayout
\setlength{\headheight}{14.2pt}

% Footnotes (see memman p 249, Sct 12.5 SIDE FOOTNOTES)
\footnotesinmargin
\setlength{\sidefootwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\setlength{\sidefootadjust}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\foottextfont}{\scriptsize\raggedright}

%figure captions
\captionstyle{\small\raggedright}
\captionnamefont{\small\bfseries\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Side footnotes in memoir}

Here is the first footnote\sidefootnote{First side footnote. } 

\lipsum[1]

\begin{marginfigure}[-8cm]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example figure}
\end{marginfigure}

Here is the second footnote\sidefootnote{Second side footnote. Footnotes are placed near the bottom of the margin but they do not sink to the bottom. I'd like to push them as far down to leave space for margin figures at the top. } 

\lipsum[2]
\begin{marginfigure}[-7cm]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Example figure}
\end{marginfigure}
\lipsum[3-4]

Here is the third side footnote\sidefootnote{Third side footnote. } 

\end{document}
```

and its output:

[image]

Comment: No answer, just an observation: The `\settypeblocksize` command changes the page height but has no effect on the side footnotes. If I delete the `\settypeblocksize` command, the side footnotes align with the bottom of the text block (more or less).

Comment: That's interesting. However I need `\settypeblocksize` to get a wider margin than the default.